# Is Array.forEach in Node.js asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, nodes

Is forEach on an array async ? candies is an array of candy objects.

```
app.get('/api/:id',function(req, res){

  console.log("Get candy");
  var id = req.params.id;

  candies.forEach( function(candy, index){
    if(candy.id == id){
      console.log("Candy found. Before return");
      return res.json(candy);
      console.log("Candy found. After return");
    }
  });

  console.log("Print error message");
  return res.json({error: "Candy not found"});
});
```

In the console I get

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
listning on port 3000
Get candy
Candy found. Before return
Print error message
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
   at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:367:11)
   ....
```

Is this a recent change ? It's been awhile since I have done node.js

Comment: Why do you have code after a `return`?

Comment: If it were async, you'd have `Print error message` logged first. Why would it be async? Also, Thilo pointed out correctly - what's the point of code after `return` statement? That will never be executed.

Comment: Also, the `return` in the inner function will only exit the inner function, not the outer one.

Comment: Ahh there we go.. Of course! Perfect that explains it. I must not be thinking straight today. Thanks @Thilo !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `Can't set headers after they are sent.` exception because you're trying to return a response twice - (possibly) once inside `candies.forEach` and once again in the last line of the route. Also note that any code after a `return` isn't executed anyways.

Here's how you rewrite it to avoid the error —

```
app.get('/api/:id',function(req, res){

    console.log("Get candy");
    var id = req.params.id;
    var foundCandy = false;
    candies.forEach( function(candy, index){
        if(candy.id == id){
            foundCandy = true;
            console.log("Candy found. Before return");
        }
    });

    if (foundCandy) {
        return res.json(candy);
    } else {
        return res.json({error: "Candy not found"});
    }
});
```

Comment: @Jens Using `Array.filter` like @Vladu Ionut's response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42504948/398713) also leads to cleaner & more concise code.

Comment: Thanks! I know how to solve it. I am just curious as to why I am getting this behavior.

Both res.json(candy) and res.json({error: "Candy not found"}); get's called. That does not seem logical to me unless forEach is now an async function

Comment: Got it... See @Thilo reply

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find the candy .

```
app.get('/api/:id', function(req, res) {

  console.log("Get candy");
  var id = req.params.id;

  var result = candies.filter(candy => candy.id == id);

  if (result.length) {
    return res.json(result[0]);
  } else {
    console.log("Print error message");
    return res.json({
      error: "Candy not found"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: To anyone else looking at this question:

The "return res.json(candy);" Only returns from the inner function defined in the forEach argument, it does not return from the entire function. 

There for both responses get called.